# How to split a string that has own specific rule in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string like `XXXXmakeXXmodel nameXXageXX****` for a car data. I want to get `make`, `model name` and `age`.

So can I split this using regex or another way in c#?

Comment: What is the rule saying how that data is split? Is every field separated by `XX`? use `string.Split("XX")`. However, what happens if the model name contains an "XX"?

Comment: Could you please provide an actual string, without the placeholders?

Comment: Do you really have `XX` as delimiter, or is that a placeholder for "any text"?

Answer (score 0):

You can split string using `Split()` function with a delimiter i.e. "XX".

```
    var input = "XXXXmakeXXmodel nameXXageXX****";
    //Split string by "XX" and remove empty entries
    var array = input.Split("XX", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //Take first n - 1 elements to avoid last ****
    var result = array.Take(array.Length - 1);
    //Print expected result.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

[.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4MR4K)

Comment: 1) You're removing `****` from anywhere, not just the end, 2) Why are you also splitting on spaces? That means that `model name` will become 2 fields, which OP doesn't want

Comment: I thought OP needs model and name as two different elements of string. If not then we need only one delimiter i.e `XX`. Let me update my answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP's string doesn't actually have 'X' in there, they're just using those letters as a placeholder.

Comment: You also probably won't want `RemoveEmptyEntries`? If a field is empty for some reason, this means that you'll fail to parse all of the fields which follow it

Comment: @canton7, I updated my answer to not to use `.Remove()` function. I used `RemoveEmptyEntries` for first two fields will come as empty when we do Split operation. We can use `Skip()` function but again it will not be feasible to use hard coded value to skip fields from an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to an array of keyword / value based on key words

for example: XXXXmakeXXmodel

- Identify that it does not start with a keyword
- Take the value before the keyword
- Take the keyword

repeat until you have processed the entire string.

You need to use the String.IndexOf and Substring methodes.